# Xcode linker error, cannot find lib in /usr/lib

Tags: xcode, xcconfig

I am getting a linker error in XCode 3.2 where it claims to not be able to find libs in /usr/lib even though LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "/usr/lib" and the dylib has been added to the xcode project. The later copy build phase of the project manages to find this file without any problems, but the cannot.

I have tried to scrap the project settings window for a xcconfig setup instead, so may have done something wrong there. Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Note that paths such as `/usr/lib` are prefixed by your SDK setting, so what you think is `/usr/lib` may in fact be e.g. `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib` (if your SDK is set to 10.6).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link to something in /usr/lib and not in /Developer/SDKs/bla/usr/lib you'll need to use full path to the library when linking. Add it to "Other Linker Flags": /usr/lib/somelib.dylib (note that there is no -l in front of the path)